# Do action on dom having id LIKE 'abc%'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom

I want to do some action on the DOM have the ID like 'abc%'

```
<a id='abc1'></a>
<a id='abc2'></a>
<a id='abc3'></a>
<a id='abc4'></a>
<a id='1234'></a>
```

In the above code i have to do the action on all those anchor take having id like 'abc%'

How to do it in using jquery?

Comment: It'd be neater to use a class. Partial ID matches are messy.

Comment: ID's are supposed to be unique identifiers. If you are wanting to group them together, it would make sense to use a different attribute (like `class` for example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$('a[id^="abc"]')
```

It's called the [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Here you can see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/suLsx/

Comment: @Vinoth: I hope you read the rest of the thread, or are you one of those people who settles for "it works"?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: yes gone through dude! But first is working and rest next! :)

Answer (score 5):

As [Matti](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269705/do-action-on-dom-having-id-like-abc#comment28528410_19269705) correctly stated, it would be much cleaner to add an additional class to those anchor tags in-order to create an easier selector to work with:

```
<a class="the_link" id='abc1'></a>
<a class="the_link" id='abc2'></a>
<a class="the_link" id='abc3'></a>
<a class="the_link" id='abc4'></a>
<a id='1234'></a>
```

Now you'll be able to do this:

```
$( "a.the_link" ); // this selector will now operate on all the desired elements
$( "a.the_link" ).hide(); // hide all the links
$( "a.the_link" ).fadeOut(); // fade out all the links
```

Comment: Psst, I don't think the last element should have that class.

Comment: This is probably also faster than the logic required to parse the ids for a match.

Comment: @mat - ooooopppsss! :P Thanks for that! (great comment BTW)

Comment: @ror - if anything, I would recommend adding the class purely for readability and maintainability.

Comment: @Lix Preaching to the choir, my friend :D Unfortunately I have only 1 upvote to give.

Comment: @ror - Then the other developers you work with are a lucky bunch!

Answer (score 3):

Try it like,

```
alert($( "a[id^='abc']" ).length);
```

Read **[attribute start with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LeTZa/1/)**